# Is there a way to restrict read access of a Folder to a User/Group in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint

I have created two groups in SharePoint Online

The following groups are:

1. Finance Group
2. HR Group
3. Added  two users under Finance Group, they are like following:

   a. John
   b. Joe
4. Also  added  two users under HR Group, they are like following:

   a. Margaret
   b. Janet

Admin has created created a folder called Photos, I want the folder to be disabled for a Group/user(i.e the photos folder should not shown for a Group I chose (e.g Finance Group) or for a User (e.g John))

Is there a way in SharePoint Online to restrict read access for a User/Group?

Comment: Everyone who has access to the site has a minimum of read.  If looking to restrict that you would need to break the inheritance between the parent and your document library and use audience targeting to ensure that only specific users are able to view the information.

Answer (score 0):

Your best way to do this would be to use target audiences for your subfolder.

1. Within your library settings, go to audience targeting settings and enable audience targeting.
2. Navigate to your subfolder, open the subfolder, and edit the page, it will then appear similarly to a webpart.
3. Within the edit webpart dialog on the right, navigate to advanced and the last field is audience targeting.
4. You may need to make a new permissions group if using a group of people or simply select an individual person.

That's it.